# Why are print statements inside __getattribute__ being called an unusual number of times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, overriding, getattribute

Suppose we have the following class:

```
class Klass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.member_var1 = 1

    def __getattribute__(self, attr_name):
        print('Klass.__getattribute__') # STATEMENT OF INTEREST            
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr_name)

# Now we instantiate the class, and access its members:

obj = Klass()
print('obj.member_var1 == ', obj.member_var1)
```

### The Desired Behavior:

Only one print statement is to be executed. The terminal output should look like this:

```
Klass.__getattribute__
```

### Reproducing the Error:

Run the code given at the beginning of this post at [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

1. copy and paste code into the [online editor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)
2. click the `Visualize Execution` button
3. click the `Last>>` button

The terminal output looks like this:

```
Klass.__getattribute__
Klass.__getattribute__
Klass.__getattribute__
Klass.__getattribute__
[...]
Klass.__getattribute__
Klass.__getattribute__
Klass.__getattribute__
Klass.__getattribute__
```

One can also reproduce the error by running the code in the IDE named [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html)

```
OS               :  Windows
IDE              :  Spyder 3.2.7
Python           :  3.6.4 64bits
Qt               :  5.9.3
PyQt5            :  5.9.2
IPython >=4.0    :  6.2.1 (OK)
jedi >=0.9.0     :  0.11.1 (OK)
nbconvert >=4.0  :  5.3.1 (OK)
pycodestyle >=2.3:  2.3.1 (OK)
pyflakes >=0.6.0 :  1.6.0 (OK)
pygments >=2.0   :  2.2.0 (OK)
pylint >=0.25    :  1.8.2 (OK)
qtconsole >=4.2.0:  4.3.1 (OK)
rope >=0.9.4     :  0.10.7 (OK)
sphinx >=0.6.6   :  1.7.1 (OK)
```

### Behavior can Difffer for Functions other than `print`

Consider the following:

```
class CounterStream:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = dict()

    def __call__(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            self.d[arg] = 1 + self.d.get(arg, 0)

    def report(self):
        print('CounterStream says:')
        for key in self.d:
            print(str(key).ljust(20), ' was sent to stream\n',
                  str(self.d[key]).rjust(5), ' times\n')

foo = CounterStream()

class Klass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.member_var1 = 1

    def __getattribute__(self, attr_name):
        #### print('Klass.__getattribute__')
        foo('Klass.__getattribute__')           
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr_name)

# Now we instantiate the class, and access its members:

obj = Klass()
print('obj.member_var1 == ', obj.member_var1)   
foo.report()
```

For [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit), the output is:

```
obj.member_var1 ==  1
CounterStream says:
Klass.__getattribute__  was sent to stream
   217  times
```

For my copy of [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html), the output is:

```
obj.member_var1 ==  1
CounterStream says:
Klass.__getattribute__  was sent to stream
   1  times
```

Comment: __getattribute__ is used within the Python source code I assume, so it will be called by other places than your print statement. Can you clarify your question? Are you asking how to get your desired behavior or why it's behaving this way?

Comment: https://ideone.com/xLcqab I got your desired output.

Comment: @AustinA I am asking how to get the desired behavior, not why python is behaving this way.

Answer (score 1):

That's not something your code is doing. That's pythontutor.com trying to access your object's attributes to provide visualization.

Comment: What about when I run it in [Spyder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyder_(software))? Spyder is not calling my functions for visualization. I also had the same problem in [Pycharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm), but Pycharm was using the same interpreter and libraries as Spyder, so it could be a problem with my python distro instead of the IDEs themselves. However, I've have reinstalled python a few times now, removed the old copies from my `PATH`, removed the old `pip` from my `PATH`, and updated everything with `pip` several times now.

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone: Your output doesn't demonstrate extra accesses on Spyder. It's quite likely that you did something else to trigger introspection of your object, though, perhaps by trying to display your object in an IPython console.